# Extract particular ions from an ionized gas

Tags: energy, ions

Is it possible to extract any particular `ion` ( either positive or negative ) from `ionized gas` ( or plasma ) without spending any kind of `energy` for doing so. I want to design a system for my weekend project where I can separate out positive and negative ions from an ionized gas container, thus leaving behind only one kind of a charge in the container.

Answer (score 1):

No. If the plasma is neutral overall, you would be separating a positive charge from a negative charge.  Separating a positive charge from a negative charge takes work

Answer (score 0):

If the masses of the charged particles are the same then I think that you can only apply an electric field to separate them, thus doing work on the plasma.

However if the masses are different, as it probably is, you can try to exploit some thermodynamic-statistical properties of the species, here are just a couple of ideas.

- Lightest particle will travel faster after the plasma formation giving a certain time window in which you can collect just them.
- You can try to set up a [Wien filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wien_filter) on a side of the tank which will let flow out only the ions with the right velocity, the advantage of this is that is tunable to different ions (you do not do any work on the plasma, but you need some power to keep it on).

The final choice depends on your resources and requirements.